# Nullpointerexception when adding to List "Edit source lookup path"

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist

I'm trying to create a gridView of images. I am copying [this android developers tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) however they hardcoded the drawables into an `Integer[]`, whereas I have to set mine to what the user chooses. mListContents is populated with objects. path and pathA are both initiated with a value. This is all confirmed with the debugger. When it gets to `mList.add(pathA)` it throws a nullpointerexception. When debugging it says "source not found" in the ActivityThread and gives me the option to "Edit source lookup path". Any issues changing from the tutorials `Integer[]` to a `List<Integer>`?

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mMenuId;
    dbhelper db; 

    List<ClothingItem> mListContents;
    List<Integer> mList;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int menuId) {
        mListContents = new ArrayList<ObjectGeneric>();
        mContext = c;
        mMenuId = menuId;
        db = new dbhelper(mContext);
        setList(mMenuId);
        setDrawableList();
    }

 private void setDrawableList(){
            for(ObjectGeneric item : mListContents){
                int path = item.getImagePath();
                Integer pathA = (Integer) path;
                mList.add(pathA);
            }
        }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mList.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance, it looks like you're not initializing mList, so a null pointer exception is correct. Try initializing it, like so:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c, int menuId) {
    mListContents = new ArrayList<ClothingItem>();
    mList = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // <---  here

    mContext = c;
    mMenuId = menuId;
    db = new dbhelper(mContext);
    setList(mMenuId);
    setDrawableList();
}
```

Comment: This should definitely be it thank you. mListContents is initiated but mList is not! Will mark as answer when confirmed. Thanks!